# Why does Voting Cost SOL?

Tags: validator

I learned that voting costs are the most expensive validator costs, my question is why do validators need to pay to vote at all.

I know it probably has something to do with how Solana works fundamentally but I can't figure out or find why.

Answer (score 2):

My understanding is that voting costs Sol to avoid spam and malicious validators. Overall, any fees on most blockchains are to prevent spam and malicious behavior.

Additionally, the price of this has become more expensive as the price of Solana has risen.

Answer (score 1):

Any transaction on the Solana network costs SOL, and voting is considered a transaction. The cost of voting in Solana is determined by the network itself through a predefined mechanism where validators are required to spend SOL each day for voting transactions, regardless of whether they become leaders or not